# What pairs of champions make a good kill lane bot?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the idea of a bot “kill lane”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63976/what-is-the-idea-of-a-bot-kill-lane)

I am looking for champions to play a kill lane with my friend for bot lane. I know about some of the standard ones like Jarven and Leona, but I'm looking for more options.

I have seen the previous post on kill lanes, but i am specifically looking for examples of kill lanes. The previous post covered what a kill lane is, with only a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

Singed/Blitz/Alistar and Graves.

Push/Pull enemy towards Graves, and unleash the fury of Buckshot. If you're running Alistar, have him pop them up, Graves dashes forwards in front of them, and by the time they're past him, it's buckshot time again. Pepper in a few auto-attacks (aided by the Attack Speed steroids on dash), and you'll take down anyone

Another interesting one is Zilean + Twitch. Twitch goes invisible, Zilean puts a bomb on his head, Twitch runs in, bomb goes off, twitch runs out. Enemies can't see/target Twitch, and can't even see the source of damage. Given the damage of time-bombs, and the amazing burst Twitch gets when coming out of stealth, a Twitch running flat Attack Damage runes will destroy all opponents for the first 6 or so levels fairly easily.